# How to model the needle/spiral of a badge/button?

Tags: modeling, path, bevel

I try to model a badge/button and now I’m having some trouble to model the half-spiral of the needle (see picture).
My result is ok I think, but it was hard to get there via two circle paths, then deleting just a quarter of one and finally merging the two circles together. I also tried to build it via Curve > Curve spirals but there is no basis from which a good result could be achieved.

So I’m interested now to know how some of you would solve it, perhaps there is a much easier way to do it.

EDIT: the first picture is **not** my result, it’s just a reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Circle and a **Screw modifier** :
[image]

Note that the object origin will be used as the screw axis, that's why I offseted it in my picture. But you can also use an Empty as an axis, just use the AxisObject field for that.

Answer (score 4):

Because the whole object, to work, is not geometrically perfect (nothing is quite parallel, there are slight bends everywhere,) You might be tempted to model the whole object as one curve, starting with an Curve > Spiral, and <kbd>E</kbd> extruding from there. Even though, in Blender, it is a bit more awkward to model curves than meshes, most of the time. I think your method looks pretty good...

This is a pure curve, with its native bevel, and a taper object for the tip:

[image]